# How to reduce List depend on id (duplicate), but keep merge child array Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

In my code, I need to reduce a List depending on the id duplicate but keep merging the child array Flutter.

specifically I have 1 List with items with the same id but different and options. I need to reduce the number of Lists with different ids and options to be merged from items with the same id.

Source Object:

```
"optionGroups": [
                          {
                               "name": "CHỌN SIZE",
                               "optionGroupId": 1557,
                               "options": [
                                    {
                                         "name": "Size L",
                                         "price": 12.0,
                                         "optionId": 6734
                                    }
                               ]
                          },
                          {
                               "name": "TOPPING",
                               "optionGroupId": 1558,
                               "options": [
                                    {
                                         "name": "Đường Nâu",
                                         "price": 12.0,
                                         "optionId": 6732
                                    }
                               ]
                          },
                          {
                               "name": "TOPPING",
                               "optionGroupId": 1558,
                               "options": [
                                    {
                                         "name": "Thạch Dừa",
                                         "price": 8.0,
                                         "optionId": 6731
                                    }
                               ]
                          }
                     ]
```

And expected result.

```
"optionGroups": [
                          {
                               "name": "CHỌN SIZE",
                               "optionGroupId": 1557,
                               "options": [
                                    {
                                         "name": "Size L",
                                         "price": 12.0,
                                         "optionId": 6734
                                    }
                               ]
                          },
                          {
                               "name": "TOPPING",
                               "optionGroupId": 1558,
                               "options": [
                                    {
                                         "name": "Đường Nâu",
                                         "price": 12.0,
                                         "optionId": 6732
                                    },
                                    {
                                         "name": "Thạch Dừa",
                                         "price": 8.0,
                                         "optionId": 6731
                                    }
                               ]
                          },
                     ]
```

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: What you can do is to save these values as HashMap with id as key and then remove duplicate keys or create a set to  delete duplicate values.

Comment: Can u help me expand it? Thank you!

Comment: use [groupListsBy](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/IterableExtension/groupListsBy.html) extension method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
final filteredItems = <Map<String,dynamic>>[];
  for (final item in items) {
    int? index;
    Map<String,dynamic> newItem = item;
    for (final filteredItem in filteredItems) {
      if (filteredItem['optionGroupId'] == item['optionGroupId']) {
        index = filteredItems.indexOf(filteredItem);
        newItem['options'].addAll(filteredItem['options']);
      }
   }
    if (index == null) {
      filteredItems.add(item);
    } else {
      filteredItems[index] = item;
      
    }
 }
```